# regex in match-function doesn't work in bigger if-statement

Tags: java, regex, if-statement

I'm trying to check if a setting isn't set correctly or missing in my Java application. Since I have a few settings I have a longer if-statement, including some String.match() functions with regex pattern.
However when I combine all these statements it doesn't work as expected in only one case. If I split the statement in multiple statements it works.

Here is my code:

```
// useResource and useCode are boolean, all other variables are Strings

if (
    ( useResource && resourceName.isEmpty() )
    || username.isEmpty()
    || password.isEmpty()
    || !serverURL.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(/.+)?")
    || !serverURL.matches("^([0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(/.+)?")
    || serverURL.matches("/$")
    || (useCode && !code.matches("[0-1]{5}"))
)
{
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

The regex patterns used on the *serverURL* variable should check if the content looks like a DNS name (www.example1.com, www.sub.example2.com, www.example1.com/..., www.sub.example2.com/...) or an IP (192.168.0.1 or 192.168.0.1/...) AND it should not end with a slash.

So in conclusion: if some settings aren't set or not set correctly, I want the function to return true.

Like I already mentioned the function works, except if the variable *serverURL* contains a DNS name. Then I always get a false. But when I use a construct like the following, it works:

```
int settingsMissing = 0;

if (useResource && resourceName.isEmpty())
    settingsMissing++;

if (username.isEmpty())
    settingsMissing++;

if (password.isEmpty())
    settingsMissing++;

if (!serverURL.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(/.+)?"))
    settingsMissing++;

if (!serverURL.matches("^([0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(/.+)?"))
    settingsMissing++;

if (serverURL.matches("/$"))
    settingsMissing++;

if (useCode && !code.matches("[0-1]{5}"))
    settingsMissing++;

if (settingsMissing > 1 /*greater 1 because it can only a be DNS Name or an IP address*/ ) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Do I miss something or doesn't the big if-statement work in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem, but haven't tested it yet. It seems, that I made a logical mistake. An IP address will not cause a *true* return, because it matches both regex patterns but a DNS name will only match the regex pattern designed for the DNS name and not the one designed for the IP-address, so it will always cause *true*. I think I have to combine these two patterns like this:

```
if ( [...]
   || (
       !serverURL.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(/.+)?")
       &&
       !serverURL.matches("^([0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(/.+)?")
      )
   || [...] )
{ [...] }
```

Sorry, if I wasted your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Pattern** and **Matcher** for things related to regex in java.

Ex:

```
String URL =// things to be compared with the regex 

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/\\{\\w+\\}/");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(URL);

if (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println("Found");
} else {
   System.out.println("Match not found");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. It still gives me _true_ when there is a DNS name inserted.